# Eclipse won't open a file

Tags: html, eclipse, twig

In one of the *.html.twig files of my project, I was just editing a piece of javascript (just as usual).

And suddenly, Eclipse started to play his own game. An error came and now, any time I try to open that file, I get the following errors.

(It only happens with this file and it doesn't matter that I have recovered an old version of it... it keeps doing the same).

```
Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized.

java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.IntStack.push(IntStack.java:88)
at com.dubture.twig.core.documentModel.parser.TwigTokenizer.primGetNextToken(TwigTokenizer.java:2935)
at com.dubture.twig.core.documentModel.parser.TwigTokenizer.assembleEmbeddedContainer(TwigTokenizer.java:1191)
at com.dubture.twig.core.documentModel.parser.TwigTokenizer.assembleEmbeddedContainer(TwigTokenizer.java:1104)
at com.dubture.twig.core.documentModel.parser.TwigTokenizer.primGetNextToken(TwigTokenizer.java:2251)
at com.dubture.twig.core.documentModel.parser.TwigTokenizer.getNextToken(TwigTokenizer.java:1359)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XMLSourceParser.getNextRegion(XMLSourceParser.java:189)
at com.dubture.twig.core.documentModel.parser.TwigSourceParser.parseNodes(TwigSourceParser.java:103)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.parser.XMLSourceParser.getDocumentRegions(XMLSourceParser.java:173)
at com.dubture.twig.core.documentModel.parser.TwigSourceParser.getDocumentRegions(TwigSourceParser.java:56)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser._core_reparse_text(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:355)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser.core_reparse(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:752)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser.reparse(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:1401)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.StructuredDocumentReParser.reparse(StructuredDocumentReParser.java:1333)
at com.dubture.twig.core.documentModel.parser.TwigStructuredDocumentReParser.reparse(TwigStructuredDocumentReParser.java:166)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.updateModel(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2713)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.internalReplaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:1923)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.replaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2423)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.set(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2935)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.setDocumentContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:575)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.initializeFileBufferContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:286)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.create(ResourceFileBuffer.java:245)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.TextFileBufferManager.connect(TextFileBufferManager.java:112)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:559)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.editor.SourceModuleDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(SourceModuleDocumentProvider.java:1240)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.editor.SourceModuleDocumentProvider.connect(SourceModuleDocumentProvider.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4213)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1451)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor.doSetInput(TextEditor.java:169)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.doSetInput(StructuredTextEditor.java:1918)
at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.PHPStructuredEditor.doSetInput(PHPStructuredEditor.java:2338)
at com.dubture.twig.ui.editor.TwigStructuredEditor.doSetInput(TwigStructuredEditor.java:193)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3200)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow$1.run(ApplicationWindow.java:759)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.run(ApplicationWindow.java:756)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2649)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3218)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3245)
at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.init(StructuredTextEditor.java:2595)
at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.editor.PHPStructuredEditor.init(PHPStructuredEditor.java:1200)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:828)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1459)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:972)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3938)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3615)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3938)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3615)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Twig parser.  Probably you have an error in your Twig model that's exposing a subtle bug in the parser. You should check on the Google group for Twig, where you're much more likely to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I agree with @JimGarrison that it looks like a bug, but from the stacktrace I guess it is a bug in a Twig Eclipse Plugin not a twig parser, so I suggest you try nightly build of a plugin and if it does not work either, report a bug to the developer. Here is a Github repo https://github.com/pulse00/Twig-Eclipse-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Ran across the same issue as you and your question was first in the google search. Seems like this is a [bug in Eclipse WTP project](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344723). It has been resolved in version WTP version 3.4.2